# Sed replace words missing one letter with the full word

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have loads of files that need to contain the name

`Jacqueline`

But instead, they contain the following:

`Jacquelin`

but also sometimes

`fooJacquelinbar` or

`123Jacquelin123` or

`/Jacquelin/`

How do I replace every instance of `Jacquelin` with `Jacqueline`, without ending up with things like `Jacquelinee`?

What I've tried is:

`find . -name '*' -type f -exec sed -i 's/\bJacquelin\b/Jacqueline/g' {} +`

But this will not replace instances where anything is attached to `"Jacquelin"` (doesn't match the whole word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try also

```
sed  's/\(Jacquelin\)e\?/\1e/g' file
```

or

```
sed -r 's/(Jacquelin)e?/\1e/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Perl to utilise negative look-aheads

```
perl -pe 's/Jacquelin(?!e)/Jacqueline/g'
```

which will replace when `Jacquelin` is not immediately followed by the character `e` (this includes if there isn't a character after)

To batch edit files in-place, you can add the `-i` flag:

```
find . -name '*' -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/Jacquelin(?!e)/Jacqueline/g' {} +
```

Remember to backup before hand as the operation isn't reversible